# Unusual Feynman Integrals at Two-Loops

Tags: conformal-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, correlation-functions

I'm studying a very particular conformal field theory where unusual Feynman integrals appear when I'm trying to evaluate a two-loop correlator (in position space). These integrals are on the form
$\int_0^1du\frac{\text{Log}(b^2 + (a^2 - b^2)u)}{\sqrt{b^2 + (a^2 - b^2)u}} \ , \ \int_0^1du\frac{\text{Log}[u(1 - u)]}{\sqrt{b^2 + (a^2 - b^2)u}}$ and $\int_\mathbb{R^3}\frac{dzdw}{(x - z)^2(y - w)^2(z - w)^{2n}} \ ,$ where I need to solve the last of these for three different cases: $n\in\{1,2,3\} \ .$ Any help on solving these integrals would be appreciated. Alternatively if you know a good reference where similar integrals are studied.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume log(x) = ln(x). The first integral:
   [image]
2. Unfortunately the second integral is divergent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I appreciate it. Do you know whether it's possible to regularize the second integral. If I'm able to isolate the divergence I can add a counterterm that removes it.

Comment: @A.Dunder
You're welcome. I edited my post above.

Comment: How did you find this? Did you use a program or did you do a couple of suitable variables changes? 

Edit: Nevermind I managed to do it with Mathematica.

Comment: I did a few integration by parts. Please note: I don't use any program for calculation, it would kill all the fun, but feel free to check the results if you like.